# How to change lid close behavior to do nothing?

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop

I just want my laptop to keep running as usual with the lid closed. I have looked at several similar questions and tried the below methods already. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Methods I have tried:

- Gnome Tweaks - disable the automatic suspend on lid close
- edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

  ```
  HandleLidSwitch=ignore
  HandleListSwitchExternalPower=ignore
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
  LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
  ```

I am using:

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
- Release:        22.04
- Codename:       jammy

Laptop Details:

- ASUS ROG GL552VW-DH71
- GPU GeForce GTX 960M 2GB VRAM
- 16GB DDR4
- Intel i7 CPU

Comment: When you edited ` /etc/systemd/logind.conf` did you remove the hash (#) before the lines where you added "ignore"?

Comment: That was it John! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> When you edited  `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` did you remove the hash
> (#) before the lines where you added "ignore"? –  John Carter

I realized I did not, and it fixed my problem. Silly mistake on my part, thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`:

```
IgnoreLid
```

to be:

```
IgnoreLid=true
```

And then restart the Upower service by:

```
service upower restart
```

This seems to have worked for some people who were trying to get the same result as you, and I hope it helps.

Comment: This may work. However, the first line in the file says: `Only the system vendor should modify this file,` and then it goes on to say: `ordinary users should not have to change anything.`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well, if nothing else works. . .

Comment: if you remember and the OP accepts your answer, send me a reply. I also posted an answer and am curious how this lid case is "closed"

Comment: Alright, @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
```

If the printed reply is not `nothing` then use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
```

Then repeat the first command and the response should be `nothing`.

There is no need to reboot and the result should be persistent across reboots.

Comment: Hey, You told me to remind you, so I did

Comment: @JohnCarter Thanks for the reminder. I voted to close the question with the other two voters who beat me to it.